# Any star-system list indexed by proximity?

Tags: solar-system, exoplanet

Does anyone know where I can find a list indexed by Earth-proximity with all the star-systems or exo-planets with appropriate conditions for human direct exploration?

It is not necessary to have habitable planets, it's just for scientific/industrial purposes.

I'm looking for an exo-planet or exo-moon with:

- Earth-like size and gravity
- with a non-thin atmosphere
- arid, so people couldn't walk without protection, forcing them to mostly stay underground
- must be in the Milky Way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia [has a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_stars_and_brown_dwarfs#List) within 5.0 parsecs.  )It's good enough for Han Solo to perform the Kessel Run.)

The table can be sorted by any column including distance, in ascending or descending order, then copy/pasted to Excel or another format as indicated by the red arrow in this screen capture of the table.

[image: The table can be sorted by any column including distance, in ascending or descending order, then copy/pasted to Excel or another format as indicated by the red arrow in this screen capture of the table]

---

And another list as [a song](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/The_Stars_Nearest_To_Me) here, complete with a video of Sheldon singing them!

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.johnstonsarchive.net/astro/nearstar.html
which list planets and stars to 25.1 ly but last update in 2018.
Also, http://www.johnstonsarchive.net/astro/nearstarmap.html

I found this site a few days ago to answer and astronomy stackexchange question.

Comment: thx for answer, I will check those